# Web API 2 Post with external Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken, asp.net-web-api2

I am using a mix of MVC and Web API (both on VS 2013 -- MVC 5 and Web API 2)

Using the MVC AccountControllers that comes out of the box with an MVC Project I am able to configure external authentication and successfully authenticate users using facebook and google.

I have a API controller for one of my model with read/write methods which I decorate using [Authorise] attribute.

When the user is logged-in to my site using facebook login and tries to submit (post) I wish to use angular $http to post; now my question is

1. Do I need to add/insert some kind of token that facebook provided at the time of authentication?
2. Where do I get the facebook token from on the client side javaScript?
3. If this works without requiring any toekn and just based on external cookie, is this not succeptible to CSRF? I mean how to add AntiForgeryToken when not using Razor (I mean forms in plain angular views)

Comment: the API requires its own oath implementation, the authorize tag will not work, as webapi does not work with cookie based authentication, in fact the whole filtering attributes is on a separate namespace

Comment: a good read http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @davethecoder thanks for the reply but I don't think I fully understood what you said. Let me clarify. I have an MVC app with some api controllers and When I decorate the api controller with [Authorise] it does not allow anonymous access as expected. My concern though is with the Post methods in the API controller. For MVC controllers the Razor generates forms with AntiForgeryToken() and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] ensures the correct token is validated similarly how can I ensure token authentication is done when posting to an API controller as there is no Razor generated form.